# .NET Core 2.0 on Azure results in a 502.3 CGI Error

Tags: azure, .net-core, cgi

The past few days I tried to find the answer to the following error message that plagued my .NET Core 2.0 application on Azure Web App hosting:

> This error occurs when a CGI application does not return a valid set
>   of HTTP headers, or when a proxy or gateway was unable to send the
>   request to a parent gateway. You may need to get a network trace or
>   contact the proxy server administrator, if it is not a CGI problem.

Because it took several days to find the answer, I'm posting my solution here.

Next to the CGI error, I also found the following error code in the error log: 0x80072ee2. This is an indication that the request experienced a timeout. However, Azure has a timeout limit of 4 minutes and the error appeared after approximately 1,5 min. The application was designed to handle the request under 4 minutes, so a timeout error should not occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution after I read the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/?tabs=aspnetcore2x. In this page the relation between IIS 
and the Kestrel engine is explained. Although the web app hosting should be different than IIS hosting, I suspect that Azure uses a lot of the IIS module, because there are many similarities.

The following issue on github was also a piece to the solution of my problem: https://github.com/aspnet/IISIntegration/issues/311. In this issue it is explained that next to IIS, Kestrel also has a timeout limit of 2 minutes. I completely missed that bit of information when searching for a solution at first. Changing the timeout of the Kestrel server (which can be found on the following page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/hosting/aspnet-core-module) solved my problem and let the request run in 2,5 minutes.

I later checked the exact duration before the timeout shows with Chrome developer tools and it appeared to be exactly 2 minutes, which should have been a more early clue that my problem was the timeout of the Kestrel server.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much, I had the same problem. I was able to fix it by changing timeout by editing web.config file after my app is already deployed. Do you know if it is possible to somehow make this change during deployment, so that it is not ovewritten every time?

Comment: I can remember that adding a specific web.config to your project will do the trick. Normally a web.config is generated during deployment, unless you have one in your project that is also deployed to the web app.